# Dynamically create web pages based on contents of subdirectories

Tags: php, html

Novice web-dev here:
I'm attempting to create a local website (with WAMP Server) which collects images from a series of date-stamped directories and displays the images from each day on a separate page (images are arranged on each page by their project subdir), with navigation for moving to the previous/next day.

Structure example:

`-Root
--171202
---ProjA
----ImageA.jpg
---ProjB
----ImageX.jpg
--171203
---ProjA
----ImageC.jpg
----ImageD.jpg
---ProjB
----ImageE.jpg`

I've written a scheduled python script which creates a new 'daily' directory and populates it with the necessary project folders and images. I have a working index.php single-page site for todays date, containing:

```
<?php
$now = new DateTime();
$date = $now->format('ymd');
// display nicely formatted date as page header
$datetitle = $now->format('l jS \of F');
echo "<h1>".$datetitle."</span>"."</h1>";

// root folder
$toproot = "Create/";
// project subfolders found in todays folder
$projects = array_slice(scandir($toproot.$date), 2);

// iterate projects and display images 
foreach($projects as $proj) {
    $rootdir = $toproot.$date.'/'.$proj.'/';
    // display project title
    echo "<h1>".$proj."<h1>";
    // images
    $images = glob($rootdir . "*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach($images as $image) {
        echo '<img src="'.$image.'" class="responsive-image" />';
        echo  '<br/>';            
    }
}
?>
```

How can I extend this to work for multiple pages so it acts as a continuous archive? Should it exist as a single index.php file which updates content based on user input (e.g forward/back buttons) or do i need to auto-generate separate php files for each page and somehow link between them?

Is there anything else to consider if I wanted an alternate mode which allows the user to view project pages (where images are separated by date) rather than these daily pages?

Many Thanks

Comment: this structure would be hard to maintain, i would use a single directory and a database myself.

Comment: Thank you for the reply - that does sound sensible although I don't have any experience with databases. I will take a look at mysql.